# ¿Por qué no funcionan los templates de Razor MVC3 en Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2010, cshtml

acabo de instalar Visual Studio 2010, y sus templates de MVC 3 Razor, pero cuando creo el proyecto en MVC 3 Razor
Agrego un nuevo controller, selecciono razor, uso entity framework, y se generan las vistas,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero aparecen las plantillas de cshtml razor como si fueran texto plano, ¿alguna idea del por qué pase esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude hacerlo, faltaba instalar unos componentes que se llaman:

aspwebpages.msi

aspwebpagesvs2010tools.msi

aspwebpagesvwd2010tools.msi

que son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y listo, reinicié mi computadora, y listo, ya quedó solucionado